# Change global variable value in PERL subroutine

Tags: perl, subroutine

I am new with PERL and i am having this use case

```
#global variable
my $global = "foo";
print $global . "\n";
#subroutine call
&change($global);
print $global . "\n";
```

Here is my subroutine

```
sub change { 
               change the value of global to "bar";
               return $global;
           }
```

And here is what i want in my output

```
foo
bar
```

I know it is basic but i really want to understand the proper way to do this in Perl.

Comment: `my` variables are, by definition, not global.  At most, a `my` variable may have file scope.

Comment: In general it is bad practice to rely on and modify globals.  Instead, pass parameters and return values.  `$variable = change($variable);` is a much better coding style for most use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign to it:

```
sub change { 
   $global = 'bar';
}
```

and you don't need the `&` before the function name, `change()` is enough.